# AWS Lambda with VPC interface endpoint cannot access secrets manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, aws-secrets-manager

I have a lambda function running in a private VPC and need to access secrets in secrets manager. Here is my setup:

**New VPC**

- `enable_dns_support`: true
- `enable_dns_hostnames`: true

**Lambda Function**

- subnets are from the new vpc
- has its own security group in the new vpc

**VPC Endpoint**

- `vpc_id`: id from new VPC
- `service_name`: com.amazonaws.us-east-1.secretsmanager
- `endpoint_type`: Interface
- `private_dns_enabled`: true
- `subnet_ids`: subnets I created in new vpc
- `security_group_ids`: a security group I created for the endpoint

**VPC Endpoint Security Group**

- `vpc_id`: id from new VPC
- a rule to allow ingress from port 443 to port 443, TCP, with `cidr_blocks` set to the new vpc's cidr block

After setting this all up, my lambda times out because secrets manager cannot be accessed. I removed the `vpc_config` from my lambda function as a sanity check and everything works fine.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Internet access from a private subnet requires network address translation (NAT). To give your function access to the internet, route outbound traffic to a NAT gateway in a public subnet. The NAT gateway has a public IP address and can connect to the internet through the VPC's internet gateway. An idle NAT gateway connection will time out after 350 seconds. For more information, see https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/

Comment: What are the security group rules for the lambda?

Comment: Is there a particular reason _why_ you want this Lambda function to be connected to a VPC? If not, the easiest solution is to disconnect it, which will provide direct access to the Internet.

Comment: Sri, this document does not mention anything about a NAT gateway: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-connect-to-aws-secrets-manager-service-within-a-virtual-private-cloud/

Comment: @Marcin: aha, you pointed me to the correct spot. I had to allow egress from the lambda security group. Previously there was no inbound or outbound security group rules for that group and it worked when it was not in a VPC. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind I will provide an answer to wrap up the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments. The issue was caused by **security group (SG) of the lambda**, not the interface endpoint. Specifically, the SG did not allow for any egress traffic which effectively blocked access to the interface endpoint.